# showing error in release phase on heroku for django rest framework

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-rest-framework

Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: admin, api, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
Applying api.0004_auto_20220121_0056...Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "9223372036854775807"
LINE 1: ...TABLE "api_hero" ALTER COLUMN "name" TYPE varchar(9223372036...

Comment: Can you add the hero model and `api.0004_auto_20220121_0056` migration file to your question? The length being passed (9223372036854775807) is longer than the max allowed length in postgres, where are you defining or passing it?

Comment: `from django.db import models
import sys

# Create your models here.
class Hero(models.Model):
    my_data = models.TextField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.my_data`

Comment: `# Generated by Django 3.2.11 on 2022-01-20 19:26

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('api', '0003_hero'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='hero',
            name='alias',
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='hero',
            name='name',
            field=models.CharField(max_length=9223372036854775807),
        ),
    ]
`

Comment: Did you at some point try define a field on your model `name = models.CharField(max_length=sys.maxsize)`?

Comment: Thanks for help

Comment: @Guptag, please edit that code into your question. It's impossible to read in a comment, especially since whitespace isn't preserved but is significant in Python.